# How can I write wrist joint urdf?

Tags: gazebo, ros2, rviz, urdf

I am concerned about urdf regarding wrist joint.

If I actually make it the way I made it, I don't think it's a urdf that I can make at my level.
Is there a simple reference for this?

It's hard to find
thanks for reading
Have a good weekend

Answer (score 0):

Hi please access this website:

[Wrist Model](https://mymodelrobot.appspot.com/5629499534213120)

I think this is what you are looking for. You can check this robot, move its arms and in addition inspect the urdf code (links and wrist joints). It is an awesome blueprint to start!

[image: Arm wrist Example]

You can change the urdf online, recompile and visually check the results!

Comment: It was good urdf material. Thank you so much.
I'm only making the arm, so I'm in the process of rotating the roll, pitch, and yaw joints to operate them with motors, but I'm having trouble expressing urdf because they work like a spherial joint. Could you recommend some other reference material?

Answer (score 0):

answering here due to lack of space in comments.

Searching about your issue I have found this trick on ROS Answers:

"One trick is to use three revolute joints with mutually perpendicular axes that meet at the same point to represent your spherical joint. The three mutually perpendicular revolute joints will give you the same number of degrees-of-freedom (i.e. 3) as a spherical joint has, and you can control them in Gazebo with ROS because the two do support revolute joints."

Take a look at the answer: https://answers.ros.org/question/414848/robotic-manipulator-with-spherical-joints/

Not sure if it is going to work, however...

Another approach answered: https://answers.ros.org/question/304672/spherical-joint-in-urdf/

About tutorials:

1- Practical (but simple robot arm tutorials)

http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch

If you need some robotics background (theoretic tutorial) this repo is good at explaining visually Denavit-Hatemberg parameters construction:
https://github.com/navidsafaeian/Robotic-Arm-Kinematics-Pick-and-Place-Project-using-ROS/blob/master/README.md

I did not understand if you need a spherical joint or if you are avoiding this behavior hehe.

**Spherical joints do not exist** with ROS, just revolute, prismatic, continuous, fixed, floating, and planar. If you need a spherical joint you will need to trick as these guys have done (or tried to):

https://github.com/ros/solidworks_urdf_exporter/issues/139

https://www.reddit.com/r/ROS/comments/9wcfs7/spherical_ball_joint_in_robot_model_not_working/

https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/26187/spherical-joint-in-urdfxacro/

https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/1074

or emulate a spherical joint behavior:

https://ricoruotongjia.medium.com/s-d65d8ffcc73d

If you need a spherical joint, the steps needed are below (done by IA):

"
Emulating a Spherical Joint in URDF

Since URDF doesn't directly support a spherical joint type, you can emulate this functionality by combining multiple joints. Specifically, you can create a spherical joint by combining three revolute or continuous joints with orthogonal axes of rotation. Here's how you might approximate a spherical joint:

1. First Joint - Yaw (Z-axis Rotation): Start with a revolute or
   continuous joint for rotation around the Z-axis.
2. Second Joint - Pitch (Y-axis Rotation): Next, add a revolute or
   continuous joint for rotation around the Y-axis. This joint is
   attached to the link that is the child of the first joint.
3. Third Joint - Roll (X-axis Rotation): Finally, add another revolute
   or continuous joint for rotation around the X-axis. This joint is
   attached to the link that is the child of the second joint.

This configuration allows the final link in the chain (attached to the third joint) to orient itself in any direction, mimicking the behavior of a spherical joint."

After carefully performing these steps I believe you will reach something like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMUPI4bxpEo

Just take care that your joints and the links do not overlap each other and get some DoF stuck. Defining the joints' limits, position and orientation correctly is very important in this modeling, you will need to use a lot of Rviz assistance for that! Or getting a Gitbub project as the basis to start yours would save a lot of time to understand the mechanism you need!